# Improving functional javascript example

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

So I have this example of using a class and increasing employee salaries in an object oriented approach. And then doing the same thing in a functional way.

```
class Employee {
    constructor(name, salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    changeSalary(amt) {
        this.salary = this.salary + amt;
    }

    description() {
        console.log(this.name + " makes "+this.salary);
    }
}

var emps = [
    new Employee("Bob", 100000),
    new Employee("Jane", 150000)
];


emps.map(emp => emp.changeSalary(10000));
emps.map(emp => emp.description());


// vs functional

var emps2 = [
    {name:"Bob", salary:100000},
    {name: 'Jane', salary: 150000}
];

const changeSalary = amount => emp => {
    var newEmp = Object.assign({}, emp);
    newEmp.salary = emp.salary + amount;
    return newEmp;
};

const describe = employee => console.log(employee.name+" makes "+employee.salary);

var happyEmployees = emps2.map(changeSalary(10000));

happyEmployees.map(describe);
emps2.map(describe);
```

2 questions here:

1. I'm wondering if anyone could help me refactor the `changeSalary` function any further. I can't wrap my mind around any more improvements, but it seems like I'm missing something.
2. I tried to use Object.assign to keep immutability between the 2 arrays. Besides immutability, what are the advantages of the functional approach here over the object oriented approach? I understand that my functions are pure, but the new changeSalary function seems much harder to understand than the simple ES6 class. Plus it doesn't really seem reusable since it expects an object with a salary property.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a refactor/improvment to working code. ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'll withdraw the 1st question. I'm really more interested in answers to the 2nd question because I'm still trying to understand the principles behind functional programming vs oop programming. In this particular example it seems to me that the oop example is cleaner, but I was hoping some people that understand functional programming better than me could help me out. I'm not asking for terser code.

Comment: I am not sure if you fully understand the advantages of immutability and pure functions. Functional programming can lead to decrease in bugs in larger projects, as functions with less side effects are easier to modify without affecting other parts of the code as much. Functional programming can also make parallel programing much easier. We often use functional programing concepts without even realizing it (`map` in your OOP example, but it's used incorrectly). http://wiki.c2.com/?AdvantagesOfFunctionalProgramming

Comment: Thanks for your response. I only put the map in for the 1st example because it's shorter - and I realized that it was functional. I was trying to illustrate separating data from functions as opposed to the oo class way of mixing them and to show the differences in code. As far as immutability in JavaScript - I'm not sure why parallel programming is ever brought up because JavaScript is single threaded. Merry Xmas!

Answer (score 2):

```
const changeSalary = amount => emp => Object.assign({}, emp, {salary: emp.salary + amount});
```

As always: *choose the right tool for the right job*. In this case i would use the OOP variant, however thats an opinion.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good improvement for that function. Any comments on the 2nd question?

Answer (score 0):

Using [spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (check the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Browser_compatibility)), `Object.assign` can be shortened:

```js
var emps = [ { name: "Bob" , salary: 100000 }, { name: 'Jane', salary: 150000 }] 

const changeSalary = amount => emp => ({ ...emp, salary: emp.salary + amount })

console.log( JSON.stringify( emps = emps.map( changeSalary(42) ) ) )
```